# How to calculate x,y,z through force_torque sensor values

Tags: ros, function

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I need to know how I can perform a function to obtain x, y, z position values through the values Fx,Fy,Fz,Tx,Ty,Tz of the force/torque sensor.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/255590/how-to-calculate-x,y,z-through-force_torque-sensor-values/) by [carlos_](https://answers.ros.org/users/29483/carlos_/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-02-25

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-02-25**:
`x, y, z` of what?

**Comment by [carlos_](https://answers.ros.org/users/29483/carlos_/) on 2017-02-26**:
Position values, which can then be combined with the end effector of the robot to position it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What you're talking about is called impedance. Neville Hogan of MIT made it popular although he wasn't the first person to think of the idea. So look up some of his [papers](https://scholar.google.com/citations?user=P7S5TY0AAAAJ).

The basic idea is to convert a force to a velocity or displacement with a spring law, like `vel_x=k*F_x`. Likewise for torques: `omega_x=k*Tao_x`. You can adjust the k's to seem more or less stiff.

---

Originally posted by [AndyZe](https://answers.ros.org/users/21281/andyze/) with karma: 2331 on 2017-02-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2